# Как удалить скопом все группы и юзеров, кроме некоторых?

Tags: wordpress, плагин, спам

Создал сайт на Wordpress, подключил плагин соцсети Buddypress, а каптчу поставить забыл. В итоге имею 3000 юзеров и 10000 групп спама.

В админке 100+ страниц групп и почти столько же страниц юзеров. Примерно по 100 юзеров и групп на странице. Удалять вручную ВП дает только по одной странице. Т.е. удаление всех страниц групп и всех страниц юзеров займет 100500 часов!

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста плагин или способ, чтобы можно было удалить скопом все группы и юзеров, кроме некоторых.

Comment: Ты можешь удалить это все через FTP. Попробуй узнать, в какой папке они лежат и какие файлы чистить.

Comment: Через `FTP` нельзя. Юзеры записаны в БД. можно через `phpMyAdmin`. Мне кажется, что можно сделать это даже без знания SQL - просто выделить всех юзеров, убрать галочки с нужных и стереть. Но возможно, Buddypress вносит дополнительные записи в БД. Стоит проверить иначе останется мусор.

Answer (score 2):

1. Посмотреть на функции, которые удаляют пользователей и группы (см. `BP_Groups_Group::delete()` в `bp-groups\classes\class-bp-groups-group.php`, `BP_Signup::delete()` в `bp-members\classes\class-bp-signup.php`);
2. В функциях выявить запросы к базе;
3. Написать скрипт, который выполнит все нужные запросы или сделать их вручную через `phpMyAdmin`

Можно также вызывать нужные методы при помощи самописного скрипта, к которому подключить `/wp-load.php`

Comment: Насколько мне известно все пользователи есть в базе. И если есть явные признаки спама, например ключ, то можно воспользоваться поиском phpmyadmin.